Is there a blessing upon betrothal through intimacy?
Based on the understanding that marriage is a mitzvah for a man, are there any sources which indicate a blessing should be said either before or after a husband engages in intercourse to betroth his (ie kiddushin through bi'ah)?
I am aware that such an act is deemed as licentious in the Talmud, however my understanding is it is not a sin (mitzvah ha'ba v'aveira) and would be considered a valid betrothal.

It is a mitzvah achieved through sin- it's rabinically prohibited to perform kiddushin in this manner (though the kiddushin does take effect).

@יהושעק there's a latter prohibition, but if it's valid according to Torah law there should still be a brocho

There are some mishnayot in m. Brachos, which suggest that intimacy could be very stressful at the beginning for some people and it can cause the bracha to be levatala.

@Coreofreality all brachot except Birkhat HaMazon are rabbinical. Why would the rabbis have instituted a bracha for something they forbid?

@יהושעק the rabbis who made the brochos are different rabbis than the ones who forbid it

Why is that a sin? The method was "frowned upon" but never sinful.

The blessing is NOT on the act but on marriage. There's no mention of the Chippa of the Ketuba in the 7 standard Brochos on Kiddushin, so I don't see a reason to recite any different ones. The Brocho on Erusin does mention Chuppa, but it says "Chuppa AND Kiddushin" which can be understood as "Chuppa OR Kiddushin" and there's also an alternative ending altogether.
